# How to add vanilla javascript function vue.js app?

Tags: javascript, vue.js

for example I have vanilla JS function:

```js
if (window.devicePixelRatio >= 2) {
            document.querySelectorAll('img.retina').forEach(function (e) {

     let parts = e.src.split('.');
     let ext = parts.pop();

     if (parts.join('.').indexOf('@2x') == -1) e.src =  parts.join('.') + '@2x.' + ext;

  });

}
```

Which just change the src of image if js detect retina display.
How can I use it in application using vue.js (where to put this function)?

If I put it into mounted, it doesnt work If I navigate throught SPA pages with router, it works only on first page load:

```js
new Vue({
el: "#app",
router,
    render: h => h(App),
    mounted() {
        retinaFunction();
    },
})
```

the retina function is not important, I am mostly asking where and how can I use custom function in vanilla js in vue.js application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would expect it to work in `mounted`, are you doing your modifications on `this.$el....` or something else?

Note the caveat in the docs, https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#mounted

> Note that mounted does not guarantee that all child components have
> also been mounted. If you want to wait until the entire view has been
> rendered, you can use vm.$nextTick inside of mounted:

Do you have child components? Perhaps you need to bundle it:

```
mounted(){
  this.$nextTick(() => {
    this.$el....;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you, ok this.$nextTick helps. Now I have a retina function defined in methods. Then I call this function in mounted [in this.$nextTick] and also I have a watcher for $route and call retina function again after route change. If it is like this, it is working how I expect, but is there a better way how to do this and call retina function only on one place?

Comment: I would make a <retina-image> component and use that instead of image tags, have the component do the work.